# Почему Bootstrap Datepicker очищает поле при выборе времени?

Tags: bootstrap, datepicker

Есть форма http://joxi.ru/V2VR3GvS0334N2 , где в поле “Дата и время” для выбора даты  используется календарь Bootstrap 3 Datepicker  (ссылка на плагин https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Выбор даты происходит так http://joxi.ru/LmGqn7pFR339jA

Установлено ограничение в дате, можно выбрать только дату на 8 дней позже текущей.
При выборе времени возникает проблема, если выбираешь время раньше даты (кликаешь вначале на часы http://joxi.ru/EA4n4abhDePpMm), тогда поле с датой очищается. Как сделать так чтобы оно не очищалось?  Второй вариант можно ли сделать так чтобы пользователь не мог выбирать время до момента пока он не выберет дату?

Ошибка выглядит так  http://joxi.ru/KAg7BEJhgvRpbA при клике на стрелку выбора времени, значение в поле очищается и само время тоже нельзя поменять. Как я понял ошибка связанна с параметром minDate, если его комментируешь то ее не происходит.

**Код:**

```
$('#Date').datetimepicker({ 
  language: 'ru',    
  format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:00",   
  minDate:moment().add(2, 'days')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу порекомендовать разбить ваше поле с "датойвременем" на два отдельных - с датой и временем. И к каждому привязать свой DateTimePicker. Такой метод использую я:

```
var pickDateInputs = function() {
  var inputs = $('.js-date');
  if (inputs.length) {
    inputs.each(function() {
      $(this).datetimepicker({
        focusOnShow: false,
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        ignoreReadonly: true,
        locale: 'ru'
      });
      $(this).attr('readonly', true);
    });
  }
};

var pickTimeInputs = function() {
  var inputs = $('.js-time');
  if (inputs.length) {
    inputs.each(function() {
      $(this).datetimepicker({
        focusOnShow: false,
        format: 'HH:mm ZZ',
        ignoreReadonly: true,
        locale: 'ru'
      });
      $(this).attr('readonly', true);
    });
  }
};

$(document).on('ready', function() {
  pickDateInputs();
  pickTimeInputs();
});
```

В html достаточно указать класс `.js-date` или `.js-time` у поля ввода:

```
<input type="text" name="created_at_date" class="js-date"/>
<input type="text" name="created_at_time" class="js-time"/>
```

Обратите внимание, поля ввода - текстовые. Скрипт привяжет к ним дейтпикер или таймпикер в зависимости от класса.

> Атрибут `readonly: true` гарантирует, что само поле будет недоступно для указания даты и времени с клавиатуры. Это полезный хак для устройств с сенсорным экраном, потому что в ином случае при показе календаря на них - будет неизбежно всплывать стандартная экранная клавиатура устройства.

Такой способ однозначно решит вашу вторую проблему с временем, так как таймпикер будет независим от дейтпикера, и на него уже не будет влиять ограничение дат. И, возможно, способ решит также и первую проблему, за счет `readonly`-полей.

Comment: А как можно решить проблему с временем в одном поле?

Comment: С временем в одном поле есть какая-то проблема? Не совсем понял вопрос.

Comment: Да именно со временем есть проблема, необходимо чтобы дата и время были в одном поле и второе условие - минимальная дата выбора должна отличаться от текущей на 8 дней.  И здесь возникает баг, если пользователь кликает на календарь и перед тем как выбрать дату первым делом начинает кликать на часы, поле “Дата и время” очищается, возможно потому что скрипт воспринимает его действие как ошибку, ведь дату он еще не выбрал и там подставляется текущая дата. Для меня это проблема, так как после этого другой плагин, который проверяет поля воспринимает поле “Дата и время” как пустое.

Comment: Почему бы не разделить датувремя на дату и время, и не показывать их в двух отдельных полях? Это потребует добавить немного логики на бэкенде, но затраты окупятся.

Comment: В двух отдельных полях нельзя, заказчику нужно в одном. Если только вариант что могут быть 2 кнопки первая вызывает календарь дат а вторая календарь времени, но значение подставляются в одно поле.